# How to check user is confirmed with Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm trying to use the Laravel auth out of the box. The authentication is not the problem but I want to check if the user has confirmed his email address.

How I let have `Laravel` check if the table value `confirmed` has the value 1.

In config/auth.php I have set `'driver' => 'database'` so if I understand the docs right I can then do manual authentication and I guess I can then check if the user has confirmed his account.

Where does Laravel perform the check for a matching username and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Laravel Auth out of the box, you want to go take a look at the [AuthController](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php) that has been setup for you.

You'll see that this uses a trait [AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php) to add behavior to the controller.

Inside that trait you'll find the method [`postLogin`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php#L71-L89).

You will want to override this method, by adding your own `postLogin` to the `AuthController`. You can copy and paste the method for starters.

Now go take a look at the [Laravel docs on authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication). Scroll down to where it talks about "Authenticating A User With Conditions."

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1]))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Change the `attempt()` code in your `postLogin` method to include the condition, as shown in the example. In your case you would probably want to pass in a condition of `'confirmed' => 1` instead of active, depending on what you call the field in your users table.

That should get you going!

Comment: How would I redirect the user to a custom "You're not active" URL if auth:attempt fails on 'active'?

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class UserIsConfirmed {

    /**
     * Create the middleware.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->user()->isConfirmed())
        {
            // User is confirmed
        }
        else
        {
            // User is not confirmed
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I don’t know what you want to do in the case a user is or is not confirmed, so I’ll leave the implementation up to you.