# How to check a parameter from user table when authenticating in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to make a Laravel website that uses 
Laravel's Auth package. I'm  using Laravel 5.3.2.

I have created a field in user table called `role`.

Now I want to know how to check the users role during the authentication process and then redirect to a required view based on the role. 
Please help me figure out how this would be possible.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Kindly check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28992717/3081659

Comment: Laravel authenticates has been changed a lot in 5.3, so that answer is not applicable to 5.3 laravel :) There is no longer a `postLogin()` method, rather an `authenticated()` method that fires after the user has been successfully logged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user logs in, this is done through your `LoginController.php` which is located at `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`

This controller uses a trait called `AuthenticatesUsers`.

This trait has a method called `authenticated()` which by default is empty. This method is called if it's not empty by the trait - after all the necessary loggin in stuff has been done.

You could override this method in your `AuthenticationController.php` and add the functionality you are asking for. An example would be:

```
// You actually get an Auth\User object passed to you by the trait!
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if($user->role == 'admin') {
        // You could do anything here
        return redirect()->route('admin-dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Both comments by both gentelmen are very helpful and I learned a lot by their ideas. I have also found a link that can be helpful: [link](https://josephsilber.com/posts/2016/07/10/authentication-improvements-in-laravel-5-3#table-of-contents)

Answer (score 1):

**Beside** solution **overriding** some default Laravel method. I **suggest** an **other approach**: redirect user to a **route** which is **responsible** for redirect user base on **user's role**
**In AuthController**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/redirect';
```

**In routes**

```
Route::get('redirect', function(){
    switch(auth()->user()->role){
        case 1:
            return redirect()->to();
        break;
        case 2:
            return redirect()->to();
        break;
    }
})
```